# doesn't read the QR codes on my smartphones. how can I do?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I have a problem with the QR code, I'm trying to scan the QR code, I'm using Expo Camera, but I have a bizarre problem.

I can always read the QR code if the QR code is on the PC but on smartphones/iPhones it cannot read the QR code.
I also tried adding a box but it doesn't seem to do the job. Can you give me a hand? Please
What can I do?

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Button, Text, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },
  preview: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  scanText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  qrFrame: {
    width: 150,  // Riduci ulteriormente le dimensioni del riquadro
    height: 150,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderColor: '#FFF',
    borderWidth: 2,
    position: 'absolute',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  qrCodeText: {
    fontSize: 16,  // Riduci la dimensione del testo
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#FFF',
  },
});

export default function App() {
  const [hasCameraPermission, setHasCameraPermission] = useState(null);
  const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);
  const [scannedData, setScannedData] = useState('');
  const [serverResponse, setServerResponse] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
      setHasCameraPermission(status === 'granted');
    })();
  }, []);

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
  const handleBarCodeScanned = async ({ data }) => {
    setScanned(true);
    setScannedData(`Dati: ${data}`);

    // Send data to PHP server
    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://www.chesifastasera.com/handleQR.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ qrData: data }), // Send data as JSON
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP Error! Code: ${response.status}`);
      }

      const responseData = await response.text();
      setServerResponse(responseData); // Set server response in state

      // Display the response in an alert or other way
      Alert.alert('Server Response', responseData);

      // Other actions based on server response here

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error during server request:', error.message);
      // Error handling if needed
    }
  };

  const resetScanner = () => {
    setScanned(false);
    setScannedData('');
    setServerResponse('');
  };

  if (hasCameraPermission === null) {
    return <View />;
  }
  if (hasCameraPermission === false) {
    return <Text>Camera permission denied</Text>;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Camera
        onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
        style={styles.preview}
      >
        {/* Frame the QR code here */}
        <View style={styles.qrFrame}>
          <Text style={styles.qrCodeText}>{scannedData}</Text>
        </View>
      </Camera>
      {scanned && (
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.scanText}>{`Risposta del server: ${serverResponse}`}</Text>
          <Button title="Scansiona di nuovo" onPress={resetScanner} />
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing barCodeScannerSettings with barCodeTypes It is advised to use [Camera.Constants.BarCodeType.qr] to indicate the kind of barcodes that the camera should to be scanning for. Since you are particularly interested in scanning QR codes, it is logical to limit the sorts of barcodes you can potentially scan to just QR codes in order to potentially increase scanning reliability.

To increase the scanning component's dependability, make adjustments to the barCodeScannerSettings. Changing barCodeScannerSettings={{ barCodeTypes: [Camera.Constants.BarCodeType.qr] }} is something you may try.

```
<Camera
  onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
  style={styles.preview}
  barCodeScannerSettings={{
    barCodeTypes: [Camera.Constants.BarCodeType.qr],
  }}
>
  {/* Frame the QR code here */}
  <View style={styles.qrFrame}>
    <Text style={styles.qrCodeText}>{scannedData}</Text>
  </View>
</Camera>
```

barCodeTypes: [Camera.Constants.BarCodeType.qr] in this code snippet indicates that the camera should only be able to recognise QR codes. This could reduce the camera's processing load while enhancing the precision and speed of QR code recognition.

Comment: I updated the code but it still doesn't work on my android phone but if I use expo go it works, in reality I have the application opens and also the camera and asks me for permissions and up to there everything works but if I try to read, any qr code doesn't give me results.